# PHP finding duplicates in array and create another array with 1st column as value and another avg

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

May I request to guide how to in PHP find duplicates in array and create another array with 1st column as value of duplicates and other column as Addition or Average of other column whose column 1 values are same (duplicates)
E.g.
Column X  as 1, 2, 3, 1, 2    Column Y 10, 20, 30, 50, 70

We want to create an array or insert value in another new table

Column A  as 1, 2, 3 and   Column B as 60, 90, 30

And (average of duplicates) 
with

Column A  as 1, 2, 3 and   Column B as values 30, 45 and 30

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome so StackOverflow.  You must first do some research, try something, fight it a bit and get stuck on a specific issue.  Then post that issue and we help you through it.  But SO is not a code writing service.  Read these: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
$columnx= array (1,2,3,1,2);
$columny= array (10,20,30,50,70);
$columna= array();
$columnbold= array();
$columnb = array();
for ($i = 0; $i<=(count($columnx) -1);$i++){
    $check=array_search($columnx[$i],$columna);
    if($check===FALSE){
        array_push($columna, $columnx[$i]);
        array_push($columnbold, $columny[$i]);
    } else {
        $columnbold[$check] .='-'.$columny[$i];
    }
}
foreach($columnbold as $a){
    $b= explode('-',$a);
    array_push($columnb, (array_sum($b)/count($b)));
}

var_dump($columna);
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($columnb);
```

output :-

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) }
array(3) { [0]=> int(30) [1]=> int(45) [2]=> int(30) }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, was struggling with the same did  r&d. This was a good solu, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make simple loop with one check to make sum of similar value and then another loop to make average.

```
$new = array();
$temp = array();
foreach($x as $key=> $value){
   if(isset($temp[$value])){
    $new[$value][1] += $y[$key];
    $new[$value][0] +=1;
  }else{
    $new[$value][1] = $y[$key];
    $new[$value][0] = 1;
    $temp[$value] = $key;
  }
}
$result = array();
foreach($new as $key=> $value){
     $result[$key]["total"] = $value[1];
     $result[$key]["average"] = $value[1]/ $value[0];
}
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/897817

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i fully understand what you want, but i would use this in one form or another

```
$array1 = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    1,
    4,
    'one',
    'one'
];

$fequency = array_count_values($array1);

print_r($fequency);
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 1
    [one] => 2
)
```

Note I included the string `one` to show that the keys of the output is the actual value of the array and not simply a numeric index.  If you need the keys you can simply  use `array_keys` and if you want to weed out the non duplicates  just use a custom filter like this

```
$dups = array_filter($fequency, function($item){
   return ($item > 1);
});

print_r($dups);
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [4] => 2
    [one] => 2
)
```

you can see both in action here

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d1f6beaff3ed7f115e39ada760d4919da28935f2

As I said I'm at a loss as to what this means

> create another array with 1st column as value of duplicates and other column as Addition or Average of other column whose column 1 values are same (duplicates)

You need to give me a clearer example of inputs, and expected outputs.  I have programmer syndrome, My wife will confirm this.  She asked me once to go get "tin foil" when we were at the store.  I told her all I could find was "aluminum foil"...  boy was she mad!

Comment: Thanks for your help friends got the answer,  remain to update on stack, apology